# Can I please get a list of programming languages capable of making http requests

Tags: http

Can I please get a list of programming languages capable of making http requiests

Thanks

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as "why" you are asking this question?

Comment: @Hypnos, can you tell me "why" you are asking your question?  Just kidding, it's not important...

Comment: Why the negative reaction to this question?  It is clearly a "real question", despite what the people who are trying to close it are claiming.

Comment: Because, since assembly can do it and every programming languages (that I know of) are turing complete => every programming language is able to do it. No hostility expressed, just want to avoid see if there is a criteria, which would narrow down the list.

Answer (score 4):

in most of the cases its not the language being capable of making requests but the existence of any library creating an interface to HTTP for a language... I think you will have to be more specific, since almost every language has such a library. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Practically every language can make HTTP requests, as long as it has the capacity to read and write strings to a network socket.  There are too many to list.  Even if you narrow the criteria to "languages that have an HTTP library available," I still think the list is too long to list, and it will probably include anything you're thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Any language that has the ability to call functions from a library, given the right libraries.

Comment: @Paul: answer modified appropriately...!

Comment: Wasn't meant to offend! In my opinion every serious language has such libraries, so you are completely right